# Does every open subset in arbitrary metric space $X$ necessarily contains one of its accumulation point?

Tags: general-topology

A point $p\in X$ is an accumulation point of $S \subset X$ if every neighbourhood of $p$ contains an element from $S$ other than $p$.

Comment: Look at a singleton subset of a discrete metric space.

Comment: It's not even true that every open set $S$ **has** an accumulation point anywhere in $X,$ much less in $S.$

Comment: However, if $X$ is a metric space such that every open subset contains at least two points, then any open $S$ has the property that that every point in $S$ is an accumulation point of $S.$

Comment: More generally, a point $x\in X$ in any metric space is "isolated" if $\{x\}$ is an open subset of $x$. Then $p\in S$ is an accumulation point of $S$ iff $p$ is not an isolated in $X.$

Comment: So $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with usual metric holds this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
X=\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n>0\}
$$
($n$ is integer) with the metric induced by the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $0$ is an accumulation point of $\{1/n:n>0\}$, which is an open subset of $X$, having no other accumulation point than $0$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, missed the question. I thought it was asking if every open set has an accumulation point :)

Comment: Thanks great example!

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a discrete space, like $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R$, then no open set of $X$ has any accumulation point (points as in your definition are usually called limit points, BTW).

In spaces like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, that have no isolated points, we have that all points of every open set are accumulation points (and some points outside of a non-trivial open set are also accumulation points, by connectedness).